# Binary operation == cannot be applied to type syn::Path

Tags: rust, compiler-errors, dependencies, rust-cargo

When I use [my fork of async-trait](https://github.com/BrightOpen/async-trait/tree/feature/sync-futures-%2377) as a dependency, it fails to compile due to `syn::*` types equality. [All is green in async-trait CI checks](https://github.com/dtolnay/async-trait/pull/125/checks). To reproduce, start a new cargo lib project and add to Cargo.toml:

```
[dependencies]
syn = { version = "1.0.39", features = ["full"] }
```

And in lib.rs:

```
pub fn cmp(a: syn::Path, b: syn::Path) -> bool {
    a == b
}
```

Compiling on Rust 1.46.0 results in an error:

```
error[E0369]: binary operation `==` cannot be applied to type `syn::Path`
 --> src/lib.rs:4:7
  |
4 |     a == b
  |     - ^^ - syn::Path
  |     |
  |     syn::Path

error: aborting due to previous error
```

[`syn::Path` implements `Eq`/`PartialEq` with feature "full" or "derive"](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=4264a02ebc64c169d8fbcc1f91f15ecd):

```rust
use syn; // 1.0.33

fn cmp(a: syn::Path, b: syn::Path) -> bool {
    a == b
}
```

I explored that syn's `PartialEq` and `Eq` trait implementations are behind the "full" or "derive" feature gate, but I still have no clue.

Tried version 1.0.33 explicitly, that works in playground, same result on my PC.

I've gone through the hurdle of ripping async-trait apart and folding it back together, but this is above my skills.

- rustc 1.46.0 (04488afe3 2020-08-24)
- cargo 1.46.0 (149022b1d 2020-07-17)

`cargo tree` on a fresh project with syn:

```
tmp v0.1.0 (/home/debian/Documents/Projects/tmp)
└── syn v1.0.39
    ├── proc-macro2 v1.0.19
    │   └── unicode-xid v0.2.1
    ├── quote v1.0.7
    │   └── proc-macro2 v1.0.19 (*)
    └── unicode-xid v0.2.1
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While the *type* `syn::Path` is available when either the feature `full` or `derive` is enabled, some of the *traits implemented for that type* aren't.

In particular, [as per `syn`'s documentation of optional features](https://docs.rs/syn/1.0.39/syn/index.html#optional-features), the `extra-traits` feature is required to get `PartialEq`:

> `extra-traits` — Debug, Eq, PartialEq, Hash impls for all syntax tree types.

Therefore you only need adjust your `Cargo.toml` with

```
syn = { version = "1.0.39", features = ["full", "extra-traits"] }
```

Comment: I too had this issue with the `Debug` trait on `Path`. I was completely stumped because, looking at the source, it seemed like `full` or `derive` would be enough to get the impl, but it just didn't work. I didn't look at the docs because I sort of assumed that `full` would include everything and that it doesn't work with `full`,it won't work with other combinations either. Thanks for posting this answer.